# MATLAB Accessing cell array within structure

Tags: matlab, structure, cell, octave

Suppose I have a dataset called `data` that was created from `dataset(xls2struct('file.xls')`:

```
             subj_CDI: {1166x1 cell}
      age_at_test_CDI: [1166x1 double]
developmental_age_CDI: [1166x1 double]
```

The expression:

```
data(data.developmental_age_group_CDI==3, 'subj_CDI')
```

Will return cells from `data.subj_CDI`. No problem.

However, if I try to search by a cell matching "HA18", by this expression:

```
data(data.subj_CDI=={'HA18'}, 'developmental_age_group_CDI')
```

I get this error:

```
??? Undefined function or method 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

I understand that this is a data mismatch, but I can't figure out how to get around it...I've tried to convert `data.subj_CDI` to a struct, but wasn't successful accessing it...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `strcmp` instead. It will give you the index of the element (or elements!) that you are looking for.

```
index = strcmp('HA18',data.subj_CDI);
```

Then to get the value/values, use

```
data.age_at_test_CDI{index}
```

Comment: I forgot that `strcmp` directly supports comparing cells and strings.  This is a cleaner answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen this in the MATLAB documentation. In the "hospital" dataset that comes preloaded in MATLAB, the strings seem to be stored within fields as structure arrays of strings...whereas XLS2STRUCT creates cell arrays within a structure. Since I only have 2 or three fields that are strings, I'm wondering if it's easier to convert them to arrays of strings within the dataset. I'm not sure if I'm being clear, but I sincerely appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The Matlab function `cellfun` is used to apply a particular function to each element in a cell.  It takes a bit of effort to get used to it, but it is pretty powerful.  To look at your example:

```
cellfun(@(x)strcmp(x,'HA18),  data.subj_CDI)
```

returns an array of of the elements of `data.subj_CDI` where `strcmp(x, 'HA18')` is true (after substituting each individual element for `x`.
Then you can use

```
data.age_at_test_CDI(cellfun(@(x)strcmp(x,'HA18),  data.subj_CDI))
```

to get your results.